# UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7fb0c3f0c9b0> ,google colab (python) to fetch images from sentinel-hub

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am using google colab (python) to fetch images from sentinel-hub ..it was working fine and all but the next day when I ran the code again I got an error in the get_data() command .. UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7fb0c3f0c9b0>
Its weird to me that when I restarted the run session as a whole and closed and reopened the note it worked .. (not an efficient solution )
So does anyone know what is this issue and how can I solve it ?

here is the full segment:

img= request.get_data()

UnidentifiedImageError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 img= request.get_data()

---

12 frames

---

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py in open(fp, mode)
2894             if mode == "P":
2895                 from . import ImagePalette
-> 2896
2897                 im.palette = ImagePalette.ImagePalette("RGB", im.im.getpalette("RGB"))
2898             im.readonly = 1

UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7fb0c3f0c9b0>

Comment: Hello @chan and welcome to StackOverflow! Please create a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the issue so we can help you better.